# Transform php code into a widget?

Tags: php, widgets

how can I create a widget out of a php code? It's just a disqus code that I would like to place in the sidebar. I could just paste the code in the widget section (my  tag), but then I would not be able to change it's order with the other wigets. This is why I want to convert this code into a widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a stand-alone answer. Building a widget to echo hard-coded PHP is trivial.

```
class PHP_Widget_wpse_80256 extends WP_Widget {
  function __construct() {
    $opts = array(
      'description' => 'Display Some Hard Coded PHP content'
    );
    parent::WP_Widget(
      'my-hc-php-content',
      'Some PHP',
      $opts
    );
  }
  function widget($args,$instance) {
    // PHP goes here, like this:
    echo 'PHP generated content';
  }
}
function register_my_widgets() {
  register_widget('PHP_Widget_wpse_80256');
}
add_action('widgets_init','register_my_widgets');
```

There is no need for the overhead of a plugin or the overhead of [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)ing your widget text, which is what the plugin mentioned does.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin, [PHP Code Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/). It allows php code inside widgets

> The normal Text widget allows you to insert arbitrary Text and/or HTML code. This allows that too, but also parses any inserted PHP code and executes it. This makes it easier to migrate to a widget-based theme.