# Assign specific ads to specific categories/posts

Tags: posts, categories, ads

I've been playing around with solution to be able to show a different header banner on different categories, and hopefully later on, be able to extend that query to the post level. I've found a few options but they don't seem to be working as I hoped they would.

Here's an example:

```
              <?php if (in_category('5')) { ?>


<!-- Test_tags_Alex/lifestyle -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ord = window.ord || Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e16);
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N5081/adj/Test_tags_Alex/lifestyle;sz=728x90;ord=' + ord + '?"><\/script>');
</script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N5081/jump/Test_tags_Alex/lifestyle;sz=728x90;ord=[timestamp]?">
<img src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N5081/ad/Test_tags_Alex/lifestyle;sz=728x90;ord=[timestamp]?" width="728" height="90" />
</a>
</noscript>

<?php } elseif (in_category('7')) { ?>


<!-- Test_tags_Alex/music -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ord = window.ord || Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e16);
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N5081/adj/Test_tags_Alex/music;sz=728x90;ord=' + ord + '?"><\/script>');
</script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N5081/jump/Test_tags_Alex/music;sz=728x90;ord=[timestamp]?">
<img src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N5081/ad/Test_tags_Alex/music;sz=728x90;ord=[timestamp]?" width="728" height="90" />
</a>
</noscript>


<?php } else { ?>


<!-- Test_tags_Alex -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ord = window.ord || Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e16);
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N5081/adj/Test_tags_Alex;sz=728x90;ord=' + ord + '?"><\/script>');
</script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N5081/jump/Test_tags_Alex;sz=728x90;ord=[timestamp]?">
<img src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N5081/ad/Test_tags_Alex;sz=728x90;ord=[timestamp]?" width="728" height="90" />
</a>
</noscript>


<?php } ?>
```

All I get is all 3 banners showing at the same time no matter what category I'm in. I've tried both in_category and is_category but no change :(

Here's a live demo: http://spacenun.com/

Any clues?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You have attempted to paste your PHP into a text widget. and the tags have been transformed.

```
<div class="textwidget">          <!--?php if (is_category('5')) { ?-->
```

You can't execute PHP from a text widget by default, and I would not recommend trying to do so (it should be possible). Instead, [it is trivial to build your own widget to do this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/80269/21376).

Based on that other answer:

```
class PHP_Widget_wpse_135949 extends WP_Widget {
  function __construct() {
    $opts = array(
      'description' => 'Display Some ads'
    );
    parent::WP_Widget(
      'my-ad-content',
      'Some PHP',
      $opts
    );
  }
  function widget($args,$instance) {
    // Your PHP goes here
    // 
    echo 'PHP generated content';
  }
}
function register_my_widgets() {
  register_widget('PHP_Widget_wpse_135949');
}
add_action('widgets_init','register_my_widgets');
```